Is epistemological solipsism coherent despite philosophical arguments to the contrary?
These are similar questions:
Refuting Solipsism
Is Epistemological solipsism a contradiction?
The IEP article Solipsism and The Problem of Other Minds:
https://iep.utm.edu/solipsis/
7 The Incoherence of Solipsism:
https://iep.utm.edu/solipsis/#H7

With the belief in the essential privacy of experience eliminated as false, the last presupposition underlying solipsism is removed and solipsism is shown as foundationless, in theory and in fact. One might even say, solipsism is necessarily foundationless, for to make an appeal to logical rules or empirical evidence the solipsist would implicitly have to affirm the very thing that he purportedly refuses to believe: the reality of intersubjectively valid criteria and a public, extra-mental world. There is a temptation to say that solipsism is a false philosophical theory, but this is not quite strong or accurate enough. As a theory, it is incoherent. What makes it incoherent, above all else, is that the solipsist requires a language (that is, a sign-system) to think or to affirm his solipsistic thoughts at all.


Given this, it is scarcely surprising that those philosophers who accept the Cartesian premises that make solipsism apparently plausible, if not inescapable, have also invariably assumed that language-usage is itself essentially private. The cluster of arguments—generally referred to as “the private language argument”—that we find in the Investigations against this assumption effectively administers the coup de grâce to both Cartesian dualism and solipsism. (I. § 202; 242-315). Language is an irreducibly public form of life that is encountered in specifically social contexts. Each natural language-system contains an indefinitely large number of “language-games,” governed by rules that, though conventional, are not arbitrary personal fiats. The meaning of a word is its (publicly accessible) use in a language. To question, argue, or doubt is to utilize language in a particular way. It is to play a particular kind of public language-game. The proposition “I am the only mind that exists” makes sense only to the extent that it is expressed in a public language, and the existence of such language itself implies the existence of a social context. Such a context exists for the hypothetical last survivor of a nuclear holocaust, but not for the solipsist. A non-linguistic solipsism is unthinkable and a thinkable solipsism is necessarily linguistic. Solipsism therefore presupposes the very thing that it seeks to deny. That solipsistic thoughts are thinkable in the first instance implies the existence of the public, shared, intersubjective world that they purport to call into question.

VENN DIAGRAMS - Private Knowledge and Coherent Public Subdomain

If private Minds A and B exist then shared public knowledge is the intersection of A and B. If private Minds A, B, and C exist then public knowledge is the intersection of four domains that we might call shared or public knowledge. If public knowledge exists independent of any minds, or of any particular mind, then how does it become private or public knowledge in any distinct mind(s)? Would the Universe outside private Minds be full of all possible public knowledge that somehow mysteriously makes its way into some private Minds but not other private Minds? How would anyone recognize public knowledge apart from their private Mind?
SENDER - RECEIVER MODEL - Public Messages Evoke Private Knowledge

The Sender and Receiver might need public knowledge to encode and decode messages in a manner which evokes private knowledge. But the public knowledge is still a subdomain of private knowledge and the encoding and decoding the meaning of signs or symbols are in the respective domains of private knowledge.
I think these models alone and in combination are coherent with epistemological solipsism but not with ontological solipsism.

The gist of the argument from that IEP article seems to be: if I use an incoherent interpretation of solipsism, then I end up concluding that solipsism is incoherent. Solipsists might argue against this, but if I adopt an incoherent interpretation of their counter-argument, I still end up concluding that solipsism is incoherent. Their assertion that language only makes sense in a social context is just that: an assertion, and it's one a solipsist would most likely reject. There's a ton of bias there for what I presume is supposed to be a reputable and relatively unbiased source.

The argument quoted is ludicrous. It seems to be saying that for the solipsist to experience thought they need language, which must come from outside. Why? And why only language? If the solipsist's mind is capable of  imagining everything else in the Universe, like string theory, general relativity, dozens of consistent views of the Grand Canyon, The Large Hadron Collider finding Higgs bosons, why can't it imagine language?

This passage depends on your understanding of the famous private language argument which some philosophers deemed very high and convinced for humans it's impossible to have any kind of private language in the colloquial sense of either natural or Morse-code like or interpretable formal languages, even for a lonely person entirely living on an island...

I don't see what the question is here. You choose to start from a presupposition that is incompatible with the presupposition of the IEP article, so it is not surprising that you reach a different conclusion. Perhaps your question is whether your conclusion is true. I read it as asserting that we know that solipsism is true even though it is not, which I find very hard to understand. The issue here depends on whether the private language argument is correct. See SEP - Private Language Argument

If one accepts the conclusion of the private language argument, like IEP, then solipsism is incoherent. Your models are not counterexamples because they use "public" and "private" in the colloquial sense, not in Wittgenstein's technical sense. In Wittgenstein's sense, "public" is not what is shared but what is sharable, "private" is what cannot be shared even in principle, "private language" is one developed from scratch without any social interaction whatsoever. To make solipsism coherent, one needs such "private language". But "private" knowledge in messaging is all public.

@Conifold - Answer me one simple question. In whose mind or minds does the meaning of the distinction between all these terms arise? Example: public versus private; or sharable versus unsharable? The only meaning of these terms arises in my mind! The fact that you are referring to some other private mind which maps alternative possible meanings to those terms only makes my VENN diagram and Sender-Receiver model seem valid and coherent in the very context of this thread. In general children learn the language called the mother tongue and the capacity to learn is innate in their embodied mind.

When I am seventeen my sociology teacher, Mrs Sullivan, often says: humans must learn but animals have instincts. Naively she asserts that a newborn mammal fawn or wolf or bear cub can survive in the wilderness without learning from its mother or other social conspecifics! I imagine what it would be like to be hatched from an egg, like a fish, with no social learning, and I figure that autonomous learning is possible for some species and both autonomous and social learning occur in so-called social species. The ego, the effort to govern action in the world, interacts with the world and learns!

Anecdotes regarding intersubjective interactions. (1) Racoon puppet says: I'm nocturnal! Toddler says: I know you're not a turtle! (Here the sound "nocturnal" decodes and encodes as "not a turtle"). (2) Noise in basement. Toddler asks: What is that? Pa says: The sump pump in the basement. Toddler says: There's some bum in Pa's basement? (3) Toy money in a purse. Toddler pretends to go shopping. She hands me toy tokens and takes toy items. I have the money and she has the items. I leave my hand open. She takes back the money. Intersubjective interactions do not refute epistemological solipsism.

@LudwigV The article you reference here https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/private-language/ on The Private Language Argument (PLA) states in Section 1: Even among those who accept that there is a reasonably self-contained and straightforward private language argument to be discussed, there has been fundamental and widespread disagreement over its details, its significance and even its intended conclusion, let alone over its soundness. The result is that every reading of the argument (including that which follows) is controversial. Debates over meaning are public messages of private minds.

One could not reasonably expect such an important argument as the PLA to be exempt from the complications of interpretation. However, "Debates over meaning are public messages of private minds." certainly cuts through that Gordian knot. But could I ask what a private mind is doing sending public messages? Or perhaps ask you to clarify what you mean by "private" here?

@LudwigV - The Venn diagram is an expressed message (any pattern of action, gesture, speech, sign, or abstract symbol) of a private mind which another private mind could in theory decode and interpret. Each private mind independently generates the intersubjective experience of distinct bodies-and-minds A, B, and C. The generative mechanism might be Helmholtz' theory of Unconscious Inference. A circle represents the respective private knowledge of person A, B, or C known to each self. No self knows for sure the intersections of shared or common (public) knowledge. Self infers that others know.

I did look at your diagrams. I understand public knowledge to be simply knowledge that is, or could be, widely shared. If a private mind can express a message which another private mind can decode, surely the contents are already well on the way to being public knowledge? In any case, your sense of "private" is not the same as the sense employed in the IEP entry. See the three points laid down in section 1, para.4. So your model of language and knowledge does not address the issues in that entry.

@Ludwig V - Paraphrasing IEP S1P4 Cartesian solipsism: (a) I only know my own mind; (b) my mind imagines it could in theory exist independent of my body; and (c)  my mind infers the experiences of each person are necessarily private. Paraphrasing IEP S3 Argument from Analogy fails if (b) is true. This claims only the body, and not the mind independent of the body, can draw an inference. I think the IEP author uses his imagination to erect and attack two straw men called Cartesian solipsism and Argument from Analogy. A mysterious cause (psychogenesis) generates attributes of my private mind!

IEP S3P4 - This raises the question as to how my supposed analogical inferences to other minds are to take place at all. How can I apply psychological concepts to others, if I know only that they apply to me? To take a concrete example again, if I learn what “pain” means by reference to my own case, then I will understand “pain” to mean “my pain” and the supposition that pain can be ascribed to anything other than myself will be unintelligible to me. All the items of recognition arising in my mind are ultimately of psychological origin! Other minds exist in my mind via unconscious inference.

OK. We are agreed that you and the author of the IEP article have different ideas of Cartesian solipsism and the argument from analogy. The difference centres on (b) my mind imagines it could in theory exist independent of my body. I agree with you that mind is not an immaterial substance independent of my body. But how is that compatible with Cartesian solipsism?

@Ludwig V - The steelman assertion of solipsism is: (a) I only know my own mind. If I know about my body in my mind and the bodies or minds of others in my mind this does not refute (a). If I imagine the mind can exist in theory without the body this does not refute (a). If I imagine that mine is the only mind and that others may have bodies but not minds this does not refute (a). Philosophical and even scientific thought experiments necessarily occur in my mind. I know them only in my mind. I cannot imagine any philosophical or scientific thought experiment that refutes (a).

"I know them only in my mind." "I only know my own mind." Which version is correct?
